# Struts2 : I don't want user to access the success page without clicking submit button

Tags: redirect, struts2

my setup is as:

users goto to the action 1st > showRegisterUser > (register.jsp)

when users click submit button the user is directed to action > RegisterUser > (register.jsp)

Now, the show method is exculded from validation so the page is clean (ie without validation errors)
when user clicks on submit the validations are performed (if any error, are displayed on the page)

My requirement is that if a user directly hits the RegisterUser page (not by clicking submit)
then they should be redirected to the showRegisterUser action.

I can't write any code in execute as the validations fail so the code in execute is never touched

Please can somebody point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your validator, you can set a session attribute indicating successful validation.  On your RegisterUser page, you can check for this session attribute and redirect if needed.

You'll want to unset the "valid" session attribute when you reach the RegisterUser page, or if you don't want to accept more than one registration from a session check for it on the showRegisterUser and redirect back to the RegisterUser page if it is set.

Struts uses controllers.  The validate.xml file is compared with the input fields, but it doesn't run itself: a controller class is running the actual comparison.  In the controller class, you decide whether or not the input is valid, and can decide which view to go to from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But the problem is that if a user directly hits the RegisterUser page, most of required field would be empty so the execute method would never be called and I can't redirect from the validate method. so where to put the redirection then??                       Also can I set a session attribute from validate.xml or does it have to be in the action (java class)

Answer (score 1):

When validation fails it defaults to the INPUT response.  If you you have an execute and an input method then you can wire up your action as:

```
/showRegisterUser -> Action.input
/registerUser -> Action.execute
```

Point your "input" response to the 'blank/clean' form everything else as you have it.

Comment: at first I thought this was it, But if I point the input response (i did this using redirect to showRegisterUser) to a clean from then even if a user really missing a field no errors are displayed. I also tried adding a input() method to conditionally return Input or redirect type, but if i hit /RegisterUser the Input method is not called. If try /inputRegisterUser then it works ok. so back to square one.

Comment: @Rushi You can use the ["scope" interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html) to store state across a redirect.

Comment: @DaveNewton how does the Scope interceptor help in my case ??

Comment: @Rushi It stores state across the redirect, like I just said--you said you were losing error messages across a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field in your form

```
<s:hidden name="submitClicked" value="false"/>
```

Now change this field's value to true `onclick` of submit button.
Now in your validation method check the value of this field, if its `false` then skip the validation and redirect to the desired `showRegisteredUser` action or whatever

Comment: Well, thanks. But I already know that submit is clicked or not using this [link]http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html[link] . And all my validation is in the xml files, so it would be performed before it comes to the validate method in my action and I think its not possible to redirect form the validate method "in a struts2" way